# How can I extend the color range in a colormap plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Here is my example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a1 = np.random.randn(10000)
b1 = np.random.randn(10000)
a2 = np.random.randn(5000)
b2 = np.random.randn(5000)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 4))
ax = axs[0]
m = ax.hist2d(a1, b1, bins=30)
fig.colorbar(m[3], ax=ax)
ax = axs[1]
m = ax.hist2d(a2, b2, bins=30)
fig.colorbar(m[3], ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
```

The output figure is like this:
[image]

**My question is how can I change the color range of the right figure, so that its maxium color values is** `115` **instead of** `66`**?**(Note: Not just change the values of colorbar, the color of the same color values should be same with the left figure.)

I tried set the cmax keywords like this:

`m = ax.hist2d(a2, b2, bins=30, cmax=115)`

But the results have no change. So how should I do?

Comment: Use `ax.hist2d(..., vmin=0, vmax=115)` for both 2d histograms for them to have the same range of colors. Note that `cmax` is a cutoff: all values higher than `cmax` will be invisible (as will all values lower than `cmin`).

Comment: @JohanC Thanks very well!

Comment: I'm not sure why you got the down votes here. This seems like a good question to me.

Comment: @tom10 Maybe it just because  those parameters like```vmin```, ```vmax``` are some basic keywords parameters. But that's OK. I've understood them now. Thanks for all of your votes and answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add vmin and vmax ranges explicitly to get desired result.
To answer your question -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a1 = np.random.randn(10000)
b1 = np.random.randn(10000)
a2 = np.random.randn(5000)
b2 = np.random.randn(5000)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 4))
ax = axs[0]
m = ax.hist2d(a1, b1, bins=30)
fig.colorbar(m[3], ax=ax)
ax = axs[1]
m = ax.hist2d(a2, b2, bins=30, vmax = 115) # Added Vmax here.
fig.colorbar(m[3], ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
```